# Using GDAL library?

Tags: gdal, installation

I get GDAL library from the the GDAL official website.The official website also has API tutorial. I try to implement the tutorial using C++ and it works for visual studio 2015 visual c++.But i want to compile the program using Dev C++ or eclipse c++ version.I am doing the following steps to include the library and the include files.

- **For Dev C++ IDE**
- Toosl
- Compiler options
- Directories
- Then I add the library and the include file path using the tabs on
  the window as shown below.
- Form the IDE menu bar i select the "project"
- Then project option
- Parameter tab
- Inside the linker list box i add gdal_i.lib
- And also from the directory tab i add the library and the include
  file

so when i compile it i get the following link error
 [image]
 and produces the following make file
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

**For eclipse**

- Go to the project property
- C\C++ General
- paths and symbols
- GNU C++
- Then i give the path to the include file the library file and the
  path to the library file
  when i build it i get the following error
  [image]

Comment: It seems you have to specify a libray name or alias after the -l option. For example g++ -LPLACE_OF_YOUR_GDAL_DLL -l gdal. The documentation page https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options could help you.